# IBM Connections Cloud - List of All Blogs

Tags: ibm-connections

I am working on **IBM Connections Cloud**. As an administrator, can I get a list of all the Blogs that a particular user might have authored.

Currently I am not seeing the API's exposing user parameters, in the query.

The idea is to get a list all the authors who have written blogs, and their blog details, in an common portal.

Request any advice on the same

Comment: try this API - https://apps.na.collabserv.com/blogs/homepage/feed/entries/atom documented here - https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=API+Reference#action=openDocument&res_title=Getting_a_feed_of_the_latest_posts_added_to_all_blogs_ic50&content=apicontent

Comment: @PaulBastide Thanks for the quick response. I will check back and update.Just an add on question if you don't mind, How can I get all the comments that a particular user might have entered within say blogs,wikis, status update, or on somebody else's wall. Basically looking for all kind of data/text a user might have generated in Connections Cloud Instance

Comment: Update: Blogs that a user has written as a member in a particular community is not appearing by the API. Is that an expected behaviour